# Vue router: blank page after routing from axios interceptor

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router

In my `axios.config.js` file I have this piece of code:

```
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
    config => config,
    error => {
      if (error && error.message === "Network Error") {
        if (router.currentRoute.name !== "login") {
          router.push({
            name: "errorPage",
            query: { template: "NoConnection" }
          });
        }
      } else if (error && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        Vue.auth.logout().then(() => {
          router.push({
            name: "login"
          });
        });
      } else if (
        error &&
        error.config.hasOwnProperty("errorHandle") &&
        error.config.errorHandle === false
      ) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      } else {
        _notifyError(error);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

When i get a 401 status code, the correct code is called and the route changes to : `http://localhost:8080/#/error_page?template=UnAuthorized` but the page is blank. If I refresh, I see the error page.

My route:

```
 {
      path: "/error_page",
      name: "errorPage",
      component: ErrorPage
 },
```

Any idea?

Comment: Not familiar with axios, but shouldn't the error callback return a Promise? Try `return Vue.auth.logout().then ...`.

Comment: Can you show your routing config please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `router.push` object to

```
router.push({
  path: "errorPage",
  query: { template: "NoConnection" }
});
```

You can only use `query` inside a `router.push` object when `path` is specified, otherwise if you use `name` you must use `params` instead.

If this don't work too try

```
router.push({
  name: "errorPage",
  params: { template: "NoConnection" }
});

{
  path: "/error_page/:templateName",
  name: "errorPage",
  component: ErrorPage
},
```

And then inside your `ErrorPage` get the `templateName` param with the `$router` keyword.

Comment: `params` and `query` are 2 different things and the way I used it is the correct way. I see the route change to the correct one, it just doesn't show anything.

Comment: Look at the Vue router doc, in the programmatic navigation the `query` keyword is used with `path`, this is maybe affect the routing navigation. Can you show your main component (where you added the `router-view`) and the `ErrorPage` component please?

Comment: It is shown as an example, it doesn't mean it's the only way, nor does it say it anywhere else. Anyway, it works in terms of routing, it routes to the right location

Comment: Yea I just test it and it's working inside my project, I don't get a blank page. It's maybe a problem directly inside your `ErrorPage` component if not I don't know

Comment: Actually it's a redirect problem. it only happens when i redirect from an external app like okta